# Facebook app does not redirect mobile site url

Tags: jquery, facebook, facebook-graph-api, mobile, facebook-authentication

On my app settings I have as mobile URL this one:

```
https://example.herokuapp.com/mobile.php#&ui-state=dialog
```

However, when I try to access the app from Facebook using a smartphone, Facebook redirects to an OAuth URL for a few milliseconds, and then it redirects to:

```
https://example.herokuapp.com/?state=63903485c518f2ae5deca667b9a............#_=_
```

As the /mobile.php is lost, the desktop version is loaded instead.

How can I fix this? Any advice is very much appreciated.

Thank you very much

**Edit: piece of security code**

```
try {
    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
            'appId'  => AppInfo::appID(),
            'secret' => AppInfo::appSecret(),
    ));
    $access_token=$_GET['access_token'];
    Log::debug("BaseControl:access token: ". $access_token);
    if(isset($access_token)){
        $facebook->setAccessToken($access_token);
    }
    $user_id = $facebook->getUser();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    exit("Error getting facebook data");
}

if ($user_id) {
    try {
        $basic = $facebook->api('/me');//se necesita access token, si no se tiene falla
    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        if (!$facebook->getUser()) {
            exit("Invalid access token");
        }
    }
    if($basic==null){
        exit("Application not installed");
    }
    $user=UsersLogic::getUser($user_id);
    if($user==null){
        exit("User not registered in database");
    }

}
else{
    exit("No user logged");
}
```

Comment: Which Facebook SDK are you using?

Comment: JS API because we are doing JSON calls later. Just edited with the main security code if it helps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Arturo, I would double check that your dashboard settings are correct.  Make sure the "Website with Facebook login" section has the correct URL, which in your case, is the mobile one.  The tooltip when you hover over the [?] says "URL for your website. For security reasons, we will only redirect to this URL".  Thus, in order to have the correct redirect URL you need to make sure that the URL in that field is the URL you wish the user to redirect to.

As it says, Facebook will only redirect to that URL for security purposes, so if you have a desktop and mobile version of your app, then you need to have one endpoint to handle the redirect to send the user to the correct page.  For your case, it seems like the redirect url is to your root page.  What you should do then, is to have some logic in your root page to check the user agent of the incoming request and route appropriately.  I would check out http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/ for an open source code snippet to detect mobile browsers.  You should put your root page URL in the first field, and the mobile version in the second.

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Thank you Jesse. I do not have anything on the "website with Facebook login", as I thought that the "Canvas URL" would redirect to my desktop, and the "Mobile Site URL" to my mobile without developing myself the logic in my root page. Am I wrong?

Comment: Yes that is an incorrect assumption.  Canvas URL is for apps that are hosted on Facebook.  You must use the website with Facebook login field and not the canvas url

Comment: This makes sense.  So then, what is the point of the 'registration-url' that supposedly redirects to that URL if you aren't authorized with FB?  Do you get redirected to this URL, then once you grant permissions to the app, it then redirects to the 'Site URL' specified in the facebook app console?

Answer (score 2):

While this doesn't fix the heart of the problem, I do have one idea you can try if you don't get any other responses:

On your index page for the desktop version of your app, you can check the user agent to test if it is a mobile device.  If it is, you can then do a redirect to your mobile.php page.

Answer (score 0):

User agent sniffing is **always** a bad idea. In the entry point of your application you should determine if it's desktop or mobile by checking for the 'signed request' variable that Facebook sends if the user is loading the app via a page tab within Facebook (i.e. a desktop user). If the user is accessing the app on mobile, outside of Facebook, then this variable won't be sent.

php:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['signed_request']))
    //load desktop version
else
    //load mobile version
```